# P4v - Diff is giving error

Tags: diff, perforce, mkdir, p4v

I cannot use Diff in my perforce client P4V. It is a new install on Win 10 machine and all other Win 10 machines except this one are working fine.

The error message is :

Can't create directory for C:\Users\ myuser \AppData\Local\Temp;C:\user;\p4v\A09564BC_10.20.49.2_1666\Sources\mainline\MyApp\cmd\restore_backup#2.cs
mkdir: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp;C:: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

The command is:

p4 print -o C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\user;\p4v\A09564BC_10.20.49.2_1666\Sources\mainline\MyApp\cmd\restore_backup#2.cs //Sources/mainline/MyApp/cmd/restore_backup.cs#2

When I do same from other machines, it is coming as :

p4 print -o C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\p4v\A09564BC_10.20.49.2_1666\Sources\mainline\MyApp\cmd\restore_backup#2.cs //Sources/mainline/MyApp/cmd/restore_backup.cs#2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After struggling half a day in this, I got the answer.

Posting this for if anyone in my situation:

Just see Env variable->User variables->Temp and remove all unnecessary paths, you will get the correct diff after restarting P4v.

It should be %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp